# A generic error occurred in GDI+ error on live server. but not for all images

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+, image-uploading

I am having "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error on my live server. On local there is no any error. I've checked plenty of post about that. Poeople say it can happen because of write permission, or wrong path or some image formats.(like png)

But in my case non of them is the reason. Because I am be able upload mostly. So it means writing permission are ok. Image formats ok. etc.

But for some images, this error comes up. I am not be able to debug or get detail information about error because its only happens on live server. For same image which is throwing exception on live server, works on localhost.

Any idea? any another reason for this error that I have to look at?

Thanks in advance.

Save process

```
 private string ResizeAndSaveImage(FileUpload file, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, string rootPath)
{
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).TrimStart(".".ToCharArray()).ToLower();
    Bitmap uploadedImage = new Bitmap(file.FileContent);
    Bitmap resizedImage = Utility.GetResizedImage(uploadedImage, maxWidth, maxHeight);

    //Save the image
    string urlName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + ext;
    string virtualPath = rootPath + urlName;
    string tempFileName = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
    resizedImage.Save(tempFileName, uploadedImage.RawFormat);
    return urlName;
}
```

Resize method

```
public static Bitmap GetResizedImage(Bitmap source, int width, int height)
{
    //This function creates the thumbnail image.
    //The logic is to create a blank image and to
    // draw the source image onto it

    Bitmap thumb = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(thumb);

    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    gr.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, width, height);
    return thumb;
}
```

event details

```
<Data>ExternalException</Data>
<Data>A generic error occurred in GDI+. at
    System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
    EncoderParameters encoderParams) at
    OasisEstateUI.AdminPages.ApartmentManagement.ResizeAndSaveImage(FileUpload
    file, Int32 maxWidth, Int32 maxHeight, String rootPath) at
    OasisEstateUI.AdminPages.ApartmentManagement.btnSaveApartmentImage_Click(Object
    sender, EventArgs e) at
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
    eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
    includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data>
```

Comment: Do you upload your image and convert it to something else? If you're just saving an image received from client then GDI+ shouldn't even be involved...

Comment: I have some resize process before upload. I've edited my post.

Comment: It's only a guess but...which OS version you have on server? Image filters (for import/export) are slightly different between GDI+ versions. What you may read locally may not be supported in your server.

Comment: If you are trying to write multiple images at the same time, you will probably see this error.

Comment: 2008 R2 on live server, and my local pc has win8. if there is some differences between image filters, don't you need to get this error for all jpg format for example?

Comment: Isn't the exact stack trace available in the eventviewer of your server so we can see what statement failed? IIS does tend to log such failures.

Comment: @rene its a good idea. but I'm not very good at server management. where can I look at exactly to get some info about stack trace? is it in eventvwr?

Comment: Yep and then look for the Application log (IIS is a usermode process)

Comment: One other thing you could do is to wrap the Bitmaps you create in a `using { }` statement to make sure that all resources are disposed off.

Comment: I've got event details. I've edited my post again. I'll look at exception deeply.